# Writing a vertical scrolling game in java

Tags: java, swing, scroll, graphics

I am trying to write a game where the player is a character, falling interminably through the Earth.  However, I am getting stuck at the very beginning, programming the scrolling background.  My current approach is to create a JFrame and add to it an object of a class that extends JFrame.  In this second class, I open the background image in the constructor.  Then, in the first class, I create a new thread for the second class, and alternate sleeping and moving the y-coordinate of the background.  Back in the second class, this movement triggers a repaint, and the image is drawn twice, once at the y-coordinate, and once at the y-coordinate minus the height of the JPanel.  This current code gives the desired affect at any given frame, but the movement is slow and uneven.  I think it has something to do with the amount of repaint requests, but I am fairly new to graphics in java.  My question is, can this be fixed so the image move steadily across the screen, or should I try a completely different approach?  If my current method is fundamentally flawed and can not be fixed, could you provide some incite as to how I can produce a smooth moving image?  Thank you in advance.

This is my current code:

```
//ScrollingImage.java
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ScrollingImage {
        public static void main(String[] args){
                JFrame holder = new JFrame("New Game");
                Background background = new Background();
                Thread thread = new Thread(background);

                holder.setSize(400, 400);
                holder.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

                holder.add(background);

                holder.setVisible(true);

                thread.start();
                while (true){
                        background.move();
                        try {
                                thread.sleep(100);
                        }
                        catch (InterruptedException e){}
                }
        }
}
```

and:

```
//Background.java
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;

public class Background extends JPanel implements Runnable {
        private BufferedImage image;
        private int topEdgeY;

        public Background(){
                try {
                        image = ImageIO.read(new File("background.png"));
                }
                catch (Exception e){}
                topEdgeY = 0;
        }

        public void run(){
                repaint();
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
              super.paintComponent(g);
              g.drawImage(image, 0, topEdgeY, getWidth(), getHeight(), this);    
              g.drawImage(image, 0, topEdgeY - getWidth(), getWidth(), getHeight(), this);
        }
        public void move(){
              topEdgeY += 5;
              if (topEdgeY == getWidth())
                  topEdgeY = 0;
              repaint();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a proper game loop. Currently, your game sleeps 100ms after every iteration, that is (even if your updating and rendering takes no time) 10fps and will go even lower as your game doing more job.

Game loops is a huge topic and there are several good approaches for different situations like is it a multiplayer game or how much physics involved in the game but for your case a simple one will just be fine.

A good paper about game loops, hopefully this will makes you understand:
http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/game-loop.html

And a pretty good example written in Java:
http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0